# How to create a for loop to create dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, dataframe

I have 732 .txt files in a folder.

I want to make a unique Pandas dataframe for each of them, but without doing it manually one by one.

Is there a way to open all the files in Python and to use a for loop to create dateframes for each one? Could someone provide me a starting code example?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *data frame*?

Comment: The answer is probably *yes*, by the way.

Comment: A loop does run "one by one"

Comment: @Fabien I'm guessing she means 'without doing it manually'.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's what I mean. New to Python so I'm having a lot of trouble trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're wanting to use Pandas to read a bunch of CSVs. If they're all in the same directory and nothing else with a .txt extension is in there, you can use

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('./*.txt')
```

to get the list of relevant files.

Then you can use a list comprehension to get a list of dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]
```

with whatever params you need for read_csv in there.

Answer (score 1):

The following pseudocode should open all the `.txt` files in any given directory and help you build a dataframe for each. It does not use `glob` because `glob` is slow:

```
import os

dir = '/where/your/txts/are/'
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        content = open(dir+filename, 'r').read()
        dataframe = build_your_dataframe(content)
```

Comment: You could reduce this to a list comprehension

Comment: So it became a directory. Now what?

Comment: `import os` must be added at the very top of your file code. It is a standard python module so you should not have this error if imported correctly.

Comment: @Lauren That's likely because you didn't write the first line: `import os`.

Comment: Did that, now it's created a string named 'dir' with my file path to the folders where I have the .txt files. But how do I build my dataframes now?

Comment: Writing you the entire software is out of Stackoverflow's scope, you should seek assistance with a co-worker.